# Avoid duplicate pair of json array

Tags: javascript

I am making a matchmaking system where entries will be matched if they have the same weight. My target is to avoid the multiple fights of my entries. As we can see on the result of my snippet. We can see that player 1 and player 2 got matched for the first time. After that, player 1 got matched again with player 2 for the second time. My target is to add another if statement to avoid the multiple entry. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```js
const source = [
  {
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900,
  },
  {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900,
  },
  {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: "player2",
    weight: 1900,
  },
  {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: "player2",
    weight: 1900,
  },



];

function combine(
  data = [],
  different = 0,
  maxGroupSize = 2,
  sortedStatement = (a, b) => a.weight - b.weight
) {
  const sortedData = [...data].sort(sortedStatement); 

  const dataGroups = sortedData.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const findedAccItem = acc.find(
      (accItem) =>
        accItem.length < maxGroupSize && 
        accItem[0].weight + different >= item.weight && 
        !accItem.find((obj) => obj.entryName === item.entryName ) 
    );
    if (findedAccItem) {
      findedAccItem.push(item);
    } else {
      acc.push([item]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  const namedDataGroups = dataGroups.reduce((acc, item, index) => {

    const key = [index, ...item.map((item) => item.weight)].join("_");
    acc[key] = item;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return namedDataGroups;
}


console.log(combine(source));
```

This is the result of my snippet above:

```
{
  0_1900_1900: [{
  entryID: 1,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 3,
  entryName: "player2",
  weight: 1900
}],
  1_1900_1900: [{   // player 1 and player 2 got matched again. I need to avoid multiple fight
  entryID: 2,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 4,
  entryName: "player2",
  weight: 1900
}]
}
```

This is my target result: (

```
{
    0_1900_1900: [{
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900
  }, {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: "player2",
    weight: 1900
  }],
    1_1900: [{
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: "player1",
    weight: 1900
  }],
    2_1900: [{
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: "player2",
    weight: 1900
  }]
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i edited it right now. It is supposed to be 1900 too.

Comment: Can you please clearly define the criteria of matchmaking?  Why would players enter the competition more than once? Any why in your target result are you including / wanting `result[1]`'s entries to be wrapped as individual arrays? A clear explanation to the above may make the question easier to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll code it this way instead, given the test set being what it is, I can't guarantee that this code is 100% valid

**First answer**
(with `§` used to distinguish the grouped list of `entryName` for testing purposes)

```js
const source = 
  [ { entryID: 1, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 } 
  , { entryID: 2, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 } 
  , { entryID: 3, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1900 } 
  , { entryID: 4, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1900 } 
  ]
  
console.log ( combine(source) )

function combine( data = [], different = 0, maxGroupSize = 2
                , sortedStatement = (a, b) => a.weight - b.weight ) 
  {
  const 
    sortedData = [...data].sort(sortedStatement)
  , related = []
  , groups  = []
    ;
  sortedData.forEach((el,indx)=>
    {
    let place = groups.findIndex( g => g.names.length < maxGroupSize 
                                    && !g.names.includes(el.entryName) 
                                    && !related.includes(`${g.names.join('§')}§${el.entryName}`) 
                                    && (el.weight - g.weight) <= different)

    if (place<0)
      {
      groups.push( { names: [ el.entryName], indxs: [indx], weight: el.weight } )  
      related.push( el.entryName )  
      }
    else
      {
      groups[place].names.push(el.entryName)
      groups[place].indxs.push(indx)
      related[place] += `§${el.entryName}`
      }
    })
  return groups.reduce((r,g,i)=>
    {
    let key = `${i}_` + g.indxs.map(x=>sortedData[x].weight).join('_')
    r[key] = []
    g.indxs.forEach(x=> r[key].push( sortedData[x]) )
    return r
    }, {} )
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0; }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

**Second solution** using js `new Set()` (no needs of `§`)

```js
const source = 
  [ { entryID: 1, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 } 
  , { entryID: 2, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 } 
  , { entryID: 3, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1900 } 
  , { entryID: 4, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1900 } 
  ]
  
console.log ( combine(source) )

function combine( data = [], different = 0, maxGroupSize = 2 ) 
  {
  const 
    groups        = []
  , related       = []
  , sortedData    = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight)
  , alreadyInRela = (setX,eName) =>
    {
    let list = [...setX, eName] 
    return related.some(rela=>list.every(l=>rela.has(l)))
    };
  sortedData.forEach((el,indx)=>
    {
    let place = groups.findIndex( // find a place in a group forEach element, use indx as track
        g => g.names.size < maxGroupSize              // is the group incomplete ?
            && !g.names.has(el.entryName)             // is entryName not in the group list (names Set) ?
            && (el.weight - g.weight) <= different    // is the weight falls within the weight range ?
            && !alreadyInRela(g.names, el.entryName ) // is (entryName + group list) does not already used ?
        )
    if (place < 0) // not found -> create new group
      {
      let names = new Set().add(el.entryName)                      // create new group
      groups.push( { names, indxs: [indx], weight: el.weight } )  // group constitutive info 
      related.push( names )                                      // keep track of group list
      }
    else // find a place in a group
      {
      groups[place].names.add(el.entryName)  // related list is also updated
      groups[place].indxs.push(indx)        // add indx to retreive element in sortedData 
      }
    })
  return groups.reduce((r,g,i)=> // build result
    {
    let key = `${i}_` + g.indxs.map(x=>sortedData[x].weight).join('_')
    r[key] = []
    g.indxs.forEach(x=> r[key].push( sortedData[x]) )
    return r
    }, {} )
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0; }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll study about this if this is flexible for my code since in the future, i will add more validations. Thank you.

Comment: I have tested your code now and added my validations and it works perfectly. Just another question. What does this "§" mean? It's my first time to encounter that. Also. Is it okay to give a little explanation about what you did in order to improve my code? Thank you

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer this character only serves as a separator between the values of entryName, to ensure that they are always unique in each group. But rereading my code, I tell myself that I was a bit too fast, and I work on a second answer; but I miss an important information before: are the entryNames sufficient to determine the composition of the groups? (or in other words: can there be 2 identical entryNames but with 2 different weights, thus making 2 distinct entries?)

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer I added a new version with no use of `§` tricks. There is also more comments

Comment: Sorry super late reply. Understood. Thank you for these. I super appreciate it.

Comment: Hello @Mister Jojo. If you have some free time, i hope you can take a look at this problem of Mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491731/add-another-validation-to-avoid-joining-the-array  

Just need more validation to achieve my target. I have used your code and i need to add more validation. Thank you